# EJS share data between 2 pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Please tell me how to share data between 2 pages using EJS, if it's possible.

I'm getting json with some data on page1 and I need to share it on page2.

Right now I'm using another query in database(access data by link), but I want to reduce network traffic. 
Here I get the data:

```
router.get('/page1', function(req, res) {
   res.render('page1',{'result' : result} );
}
```

I want to click some button on page 1 and open page 2 with data from result[someIndex]

```
 router.get('/page2', function(req, res) {
       res.render('page2');
 }
```

Comment: What kind of data is `result`? Does its values change between page1 and 2?

Comment: result is json. And data doesnt change (still the same) between pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - You can use Local Storage

2 - You can pass data with link

```
router.get('/page1', function(req, res) {
   res.render('page1',{'result' : result} );
}
```

In page 1 template ,

```
<a href="page2?name=value">link</a>
```

Then access it in page 2 like

```
app.get('/page2', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('page2', {query : req.query.name});
});
```

3 - Pass data from root to both pages

```
app.get('/page1.js', function(req, res) {
  res.render('testPage', { myVar : ... });
});

app.get('/page2.js', function(req, res) {
  res.render('testPage', { myVar : ... });
});
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please share code so I can understand the problem better.

Comment: I'm using 2 solution from your answer, other solutions dont work for me and this is why I'm here

Comment: Again, 2-nd point works, thanks. But I need another way, show how to use 1 and 3 points